# Does the browser fire network requests from onclick handlers when the event is not canceled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

Suppose I have this JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$( 'a' ).click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
        trackUrl1 = 'https://example.com/tracking1?url=' + url,
        trackUrl2 = 'https://example.com/tracking2?url=' + url;
    $( '#my-tracking-pixel' ).attr('src', trackUrl1);
    $.ajax( {url: trackUrl2} );
});
```

The event handler causes network requests to be executed immediately before the browser requests the page specified in the `href` attribute fo the link. I'm wondering if the network requests from the click handler will be really executed every time and if the browser waits for the reponses before loading the link target. Is there any documentation of the browser behavior? Is the behavior consistent across browsers? Is there a difference between the XMLHttpRequest and requesting by setting the `src` attribute?

Comment: That looks dangerous to me. Currently it's still permitted to do AJAX synchronously, although browsers will hit you with a warning in the console that it is deprecated behaviour. That would be safe (but antisocial). If it were me, I'd do the google search-results style... send the user to a tracking url which redirects to the target url.

Comment: The jquery docs say that `async` defaults to `true`, even when I don't set it. Or do you mean setting the src attribute causes a synchronous request?

Comment: No. I'm saying that if you do synchronous ajax in the event handler for the link, it will definitely complete before the default action is performed. However, I'm not recommending this as an appropriate solution. I'd recommend that your outlink points to a resource that does the tracking (under your control) then redirects the user to the target url.

Comment: Alternatively, you could cancel the default action, wait until your async ajax and image loading is completed, then set `location.href` to the target of the link. You'll need to register a load handler against the tracking pixel so that you can tell when both the ajax and the image have definitely completed, then... off you go...